# Why geom_bar does not display data correctly in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

My dataset example looks like this:

```
dput(t)
structure(list(date = structure(c(19091, 19091, 19092, 19092, 
19093, 19093, 19094, 19094, 19095, 19095, 19096, 19096, 19097, 
19097, 19098, 19098, 19099, 19099, 19100, 19100, 19101, 19101, 
19102, 19102, 19103, 19103, 19104, 19104, 19105, 19105, 19106, 
19106, 19107, 19107, 19109, 19109, 19110, 19110, 19111, 19111, 
19112, 19112, 19113, 19113, 19114, 19114), class = "Date"), TempAmb_Avg = c(13.16, 
13.16, 7.929, 7.929, 12.29, 12.29, 10.37, 10.37, 10.91, 10.91, 
10.14, 10.14, 9.15, 9.15, 11.25, 11.25, 9.17, 9.17, 11.94, 11.94, 
11.26, 11.26, 9.45, 9.45, 9.09, 9.09, NA, NA, 6.447, 6.447, 9.14, 
9.14, 8.02, 8.02, 10.54, 10.54, 10.12, 10.12, 11.56, 11.56, 12.3, 
12.3, 10.82, 10.82, 11.17, 11.17)), row.names = c(NA, 46L), class = "data.frame")
```

I'm having a problem that I can't go around. When plotting the **TempAmb_Avg** *geom_bar* does not display the real data, but *geom_line*, displays. I've been using this code:

```
plot<- ggplot(NDVI)  + 
  geom_bar(aes(x=date, y=TempAmb_Avg),stat="identity",colour="blue")+
  geom_line(aes(x=date, y=TempAmb_Avg),stat="identity",colour="black")+
  labs(x="TIME",y="TºC")+
  theme_bw()
plot
```

[image]

What do I have to do to display the real data with *geom_bar*?

I've found a solution but I'm lacking one step.
To avoid **TempAmb_Avg** data duplication when using *geom_bar* I've divided
**TempAmb_Avg**/2.

```
plot<- ggplot(NDVI)  + 
  geom_bar(aes(x=date, y=TempAmb_Avg/2),stat="identity",colour="blue")+
  geom_line(aes(x=date, y=TempAmb_Avg),stat="identity",colour="black")+
  labs(x="TIME",y="TºC")+
  theme_bw()
plot
```

However not all **TempAmb_Avg** is duplicated.
How can I set a condition to only divide with 2 the duplicated values?

Comment: Your data is seemingly duplicated.  `geom_bar()` stacks the data by defualt so the bars are twice the height of the lines.

Comment: `geom_bar` is working correctly.  Your understanding is at fault.  From the online help: "There are two types of bar charts: geom_bar() and geom_col(). geom_bar() makes the height of the bar proportional to the number of cases in each group (or if the weight aesthetic is supplied, the sum of the weights). If you want the heights of the bars to represent values in the data, use geom_col() instead. geom_bar() uses stat_count() by default: it counts the number of cases at each x position. geom_col() uses stat_identity(): it leaves the data as is.".

Comment: @Limey - `geom_bar(stat = "identity")` is equivalent to `geom_col()`.

Comment: @Ritchie Sacramento That's true but not for all the data. Is there a way to only get one observation for one date point using geom_bar or similar?

Comment: @Limey thank you for the explanation. Using geom_col gives me the same output as geom_bar.

Comment: Yes, deduplicate your data - `ggplot(unique(NDVI)) + ...`.

Comment: @Ritchie Sacramento Not all the data is duplicated and I need the data duplicated as it is.

Comment: Then deduplicate it in the layer instead - `geom_bar(..., data = unique(NDVI))`.

Comment: @Ritchie Sacramento how do I do that in the layer?

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

#load your data first to NDVI object

plot <- NDVI %>%
  #this will delete any duplicate row
  distinct() %>%
  ggplot(NDVI)  + 
  geom_bar(aes(x=date, y=TempAmb_Avg),stat="identity",colour="blue")+
  geom_line(aes(x=date, y=TempAmb_Avg),stat="identity",colour="black")+
  labs(x="TIME",y="TºC")+
  theme_bw()
plot
```

Comment: Miroto thank you but I need the duplicated rows

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the duplicated data of the column **TempAmb_Avg** and then plot with `geom_bar`.